# A different way to find the http referrer?

Tags: php, apache, logging, tor, http-referer

I have a virtual linux with Apache2, PHP and behind Tor (hidden service). and I want to find the HTTP REFERRER. Now I know $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is unreliable and shouldn't be used. And I even tested it myself:

```
file_put_contents("rfrs.log", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . " \r\n", 
  FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

The result was a file with my own onion address, even though I clicked the link from some search engine. So far, not surprising. The thing is, Viewing Apache's access.log, besides all the '127.0.0.1' (which means Tor is working), I DO see the correct Referring domain! The onion address of that search engine was there!

How can I have access to that info for php use?
What's the best way to do it?

Comment: PHP gets its value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` from Apache (based on the HTTP request).  Is this not populating in PHP but you see it in the access logs for the same request?  As long as the client isn't spoofing it and the browser sets it, it is reliable.  There are just no guarantees that it will be set or that it is true and accurate.

Comment: Yes, it's the same request.

Comment: How are you proxying Tor requests to Apache?  Referer works correctly if you set up a virtual host with your Onion address and use `HiddenServicePort 80 your.onion.vhost.ip:80`

Comment: It set up as documented, using 80 127.0.01:80 while apache    is accessible only from localhost.

Comment: Did your application do some kind of internal redirect between the initial URL to where you logged the referrer?  That's the only reason I can think of as to why you'd be seeing your own onion address as the referrer in your check.  I tested this with a hidden service and `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` correctly reflected that of the referring site, not my own address/URL.

Comment: There's no redirection, It's a very simple site with very basic php scripts, no header manipulations or JS.

Answer (score 0):

OK, weirdly enough, it started to work! There was some weird behavior. The self-domain is stored in an included php file and somehow it got nullified. and the test (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $mydomain) > -1) wasn't acting as I wanted. 
so I did two things: 1. I move the test and file writing code to right under the "include". 2. I took the 'HTTP_REFERER' result and cut it with strpos and substr and then just !== $mydomain.

I'm still baffled about why it works, but it does!
Thank you everyone :)

I sure got a lot more to learn.